# How do I do this query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a rock wall MySQL database as follows:

```
Harnesses (harnessID, manufacturer, condition)
Shoes (shoeID, size, condition)
Holds (holdID, holdType, manufacturer, condition)
Bolts (boltID, length, condition)
```

How would I query for all items that have a condition of some 'value'? (ex. 'Good'/'Bad'/'Great')

Ideally the result would have schema:

```
ResultTable (itemType, itemID, condition)
[Where itemType = {Harness, Shoe, Hold, Bolt}]
```

### SOLVED

Solution: Add an itemType Field to all the tables and union different selects (with conditions table as a FK 1-Great, 2-Good, 3-Bad)

```
select itemType as Item, harnessID as ID, description as 'Condition' from harnesses join conditions where `condition` = conditions.conditionID and `condition` = 1

UNION 

select itemType as Item, shoeID as ID, description as 'Condition' from shoes join conditions where `condition` = conditions.conditionID and `condition` = 1

UNION

select itemType as Item, holdID as ID, description as 'Condition' from holds join conditions where `condition` = conditions.conditionID and `condition` = 1

UNION

select itemType as Item, boltID as ID, description as 'Condition' from bolts join conditions where `condition` = conditions.conditionID and `condition` = 1;
```

Comment: What have you done in answering this homework question? Perhaps read up about select

Comment: This isn't a homework question, it's an application I'm creating to manage our inventory at a rock wall that I work at. Thank you for your concern though.

Comment: Did people down vote this because they thought it was a homework question? :(

Comment: @AustinAyers Did you even see my answer, which totally answers your question, or you just wanna fight it, which is of no use, coz you already have only 1 rep and it doesn't cause you any damage?

Comment: I'm on Christmas break for school so that should have ruled out that this wasn't a homework question. Happy holidays @EdHeal

Comment: (un)fortuantely I did not know that you are at school or when your school holidays occur. You could be in a part of the world that does not have Christmas

Comment: Well, then being rude in a doubtful situation should not be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `IN` operator and give multiple values:

```
SELECT * FROM `ResultTable` WHERE `itemType` IN ('Harness', 'Shoe', 'Hold', 'Bolt')
```

Comment: How would I go about setting a column to itemType from a sub-query? i.e. putting together the shoes and harnesses tables with a new column that is itemType [={'shoe','harness']?

Comment: @AustinAyers You can do this: **SELECT * FROM `ResultTable` WHERE `itemType` IN (SELECT `itemType` FROM `anotherTable`)**

Comment: I don't have an itemType field in any of my tables, is it possible to do it from metadata? (COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME). Or would it be easier to just add an itemType field to my tuples?

Comment: @AustinAyers The second one is easier buddy.

Comment: Thanks! Also, this actually isn't a homework question. It's an extension of a project I did in my database class last semester (I already turned in an older version) that I want to use to help the rock wall that I work at. I'm extending it, and I couldn't figure this out. It's a WPF. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: @AustinAyers I have never said it is a homework question, the moment I saw it. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use Union for combining multiple tables [Mysql Union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html).
But Union has constraint That column numbers should be same as well as datatype.
So if your column number were same than Query would be like

```
select Harness as ItemType, harnessID as ItemId where condition ='Good'
Union
select Shoes as ItemType, shoeID as ItemId where condition ='Good'
union
select Holds as ItemType, holdID as ItemId where condition ='Good'
union
select Bolts as ItemType, boltID as ItemId where condition ='Good'
```

Comment: Is this possible without having an itemType column?

Comment: I didn't get u actually ? Check union , i think it'll give your answer